# Run time difference between chained functions and a list of functions in OCaml

Tags: function, closures, ocaml

For registering unit functions to be called later, I came up with this solution using a `(unit -> unit) ref` that chains the functions together:

```ml
let callbacks = ref @@ fun () -> ()

let add_callback f =
  let old_callbacks = !callbacks in
  callbacks := (fun () -> f (); old_callbacks ())

(* ... call add_callback many times ... *)

(* eventually, run all the callbacks I stacked: *)
!callbacks ()
```

I am wondering how it compares to that other solution using a stack of functions `(unit -> unit) list ref`:

```ml
let callbacks = ref []

let add_callback f =
  callbacks := f :: !callbacks

(* ... call add_callback many times ... *)

(* eventually, run all the callbacks I stacked: *)
List.iter (fun f -> f ()) !callbacks
```

Are there differences in how they are represented in memory?

If I were to register a huge amount of functions, which solution would be the best in terms of memory and of unstacking time? For these 2 criteria, is there a better yet solution?

Comment: `function`(s) are standard values in OCaml. It's even more interesting that you are choosing a `ref`, would you like to tell us why did you choose to use a `ref`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan I edited the question to be more precise about what interest me, is this still too much "opinion-based question" ?

Comment: I am curious now: what is a situation where you register *tons* of *very small* callbacks, so that the time and memory used by your callback-registering system would not be negligible compared to what the callbacks do and to what everything else your program does?

Comment: Actually, I was just curious to know the answer. I implemented the first one to add item to an hashtable after itering through it and was wondering if a list would have been faster or more idiomatic to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you have a list of functions. In the first case the nodes of the list are function closures. In the second case they are cons elements. I don't know the ins and outs of closure representation in OCaml but I would guess that a closure is bigger than a cons element (which takes 3 memory slots for header, car, and cdr (to use the old school terminology)).

When it comes time to call, both cases are going to fetch a pointer to the next function and call it. In the first case the pointer will be fetched from the environment (variable bindings) of the closure. In the second case it will be fetched from the cons. I suspect that environments are accessed approximately as efficiently as cons cells. I.e., the code can use fixed offsets rather than a symbolic lookup.

These are just guesses. It would actually be interesting (and entertaining) to code up the two different methods and compare them.

Comment: After playing with [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) for a while, I confirm everything you said regarding how closures are compiled. Lambda-abstractions are env-closed and lifted, and their occurrences become closure blocks of size 3 + number of formerly-free variables (header + code pointer + some arity metadata + environment). Here the env has 2 fields (`unit_f`, `old_f`), so 3+2=5 words, 2 more than cons cells. Reading from a closure env is just the same as reading a field from a cons cell (known offsets).

Comment: [Amending my previous message for the sake of generality: when the arity of the source lambda-abstraction is N > 1, the closure is larger by one word: its size is 4 + number of free variables (header + pointer to `caml_curryN` + arity + code pointer + environment). And the control flow has more indirections.]

Comment: So memory-wise you get equivalent encodings (a chained list of functions), only with a bit more overhead in the solution using closures. Time-wise, the solution using closures does one more closure call for each added callback, whereas the list counterpart of that operation is a tail-rec call to `List.iter`, i.e. just a jump. But I think the time overhead would be negligible unless you register bazillions of no-op callbacks.